# How prompt shows up earlier than stdout of popen call?

Tags: c, pipe

I've wrote redirection code using pipe, and also wrote using popen after that.
And I found strange order of output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
        FILE* fp;
        fp=popen("mkpasswd -msha-512 -Sqwertyabc asdf","r");
        char buf[120];
        fscanf(fp,"%s",buf);
        printf("result : %s\n",buf);

        fp=popen("mkpasswd -msha-512 -Sqwertyabc","w");
        fprintf(fp,"asdf");
        //fflush(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

```
~/workspace/tmp$ ./a.out
result : $6$qwertyabc$zctY7qCE/1e0b4iw0E.saKy6/QvVap4Ejdh16iTDc2dTM2n0tjtam/XikbYX02i/nnAjJopuIa2hQ.//wcZt80
~/workspace/tmp$ Password: $6$qwertyabc$.32ixI96wLr3h2nfYR9opTW3KFVuHWDFyI36JID.DI1riXs0glb/pzmNvdNEaoLDdEV3UkqxspBUruOzLMVMN/
```

Whether I commentize or not 'fflush', my prompt show up earlier than output of latter 'mkpasswd' call.

How can it be like this? and what should I know about this?

Answer (score 1):

The prompt to appear before the output of last print because you forgot to close the `popen` generated FILE. Just add `fclose(fp);` before the `return 0;` all all will print in order.

But I think you have 2 other problems in you code :

- you do not close `fp` after first command before opening the second one causing a memory leak : the memory used by the `FILE` object is no longer accessible
- you write `asdf` on standard input of `mkpasswd` (in second command), but with this syntax `mkpasswd` uses `getpass` and directly reads on `/dev/tty`. You should use `-s` flag to read on stdin

The correct code should be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
        FILE* fp;
        fp=popen("mkpasswd -msha-512 -Sqwertyabc asdf","r");
        char buf[120];
        fscanf(fp,"%s",buf);
        fclose(fp);
        printf("result : %s\n",buf);

        fp=popen("mkpasswd -s -msha-512 -Sqwertyabc","w");
        fprintf(fp,"asdf");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

It gives

```
result : $6$qwertyabc$zctY7qCE/1e0b4iw0E.saKy6/QvVap4Ejdh16iTDc2dTM2n0tjtam/XikbYX02i/nnAjJopuIa2hQ.//wcZt80
$6$qwertyabc$zctY7qCE/1e0b4iw0E.saKy6/QvVap4Ejdh16iTDc2dTM2n0tjtam/XikbYX02i/nnAjJopuIa2hQ.//wcZt80
```

correctly followed by the prompt.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not correct.
I've tried but it turned out same. and also, my point is about 2nd and 3rd line, not 1st and 2nd line.
In addition, you're saying about faster showing up of stderr than stdout(said stderr not buffered but stdout is), but it's about delayed show up of stderr even later than end of process(mean after prompt show up).

Comment: Oups, I should have fully read you question and tested my answer :-( - It's correct now ...

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you for both answer and comment about problems.